# mod_negotiation and mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to configure a URL scheme that a) allows the ".html" extension to be omitted and b) sends 403 (Forbidden) errors under certain conditions. However, with the following setup:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteRule ^foo/bar$ - [F]
```

If I request `/foo/bar` I get a 404 (Not Found) error complete with a 'None could be negotiated' line in the error log. Requesting `/foo/bar.html` *does* work, so I'm guessing that the content-negotiation is taking 'priority' over the RewriteRule and keeps looking for alternative URLs until it finds a 200. In fact, I've pretty much confirmed that by testing with a `bar.txt` file and a RewriteRule that only targets the .html file.

So, is there a way of modifying mod_negotiation's behaviour to 'give up' as soon as it encounters a Forbidden error?

**UPDATE**

NB: It looks as though I can workaround the problem by disabling MultiViews and using mod_rewrite instead e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

but I'm guessing that's less efficient, and it's a lot more config to deal with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that you're omitting your leading slash from `^foo`, I'm guessing that this is configured in a `<Directory>` block or `htaccess` file?

That's actually the cause of the problem in this case; in that context, the rewrite rules are applied after the request has been mapped to the file system (and the `.html` has been tacked on).

From the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that led the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

Move your `RewriteRule` configuration up to the `<VirtualHost>` context (and modify your match accordingly, from `^foo/bar$` to `^/foo/bar$`), and it should work as expected.

Comment: Spot on - I'd award bonus points for the excellent powers of deduction if I could! :-)